# Unable to delete an entry from database using Next.js api routes with Prisma

Tags: typescript, next.js, routes, prisma

So I am working on a Todo manager and have been using Next.js 13, Prisma, and MySQL for the same. To add an option to delete a todo item, I have wrapped the delete button with a `Link` tag as follows:

```js
...
<Link href={`/api/todo/${id}`}>
          <MdDelete className="bg-red-400 hover:bg-red-600 p-1 text-3xl rounded-xl" />
</Link>
...
```

where `id` is passed as a prop to the component. The `/app/api/todo/[id]/route.ts` is as follows:

```js
import { prisma } from "@/lib/database";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function DELETE(
  req: Request,
  { params }: { params: { id: string } }
) {
  await prisma.todo.delete({
    where: {
      id: params.id,
    },
  });
  return NextResponse.json({ message: "done" });
}
```

But when the Link is pressed, it goes to the URL `http://localhost:3000/api/todo/clkgkh3t70000p1947hi24a3k` and shows the following page:

[image]

where `clkgkh3t70000p1947hi24a3k` is the `id` being passed.

Is there a fix to this issue? Or what is the alternative to remove this Todo Item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Link`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/link) component is a wrapper around the HTML [`a`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) element, which takes you to a new page by design. You need to use a `button` with an `onClick`:

```js
<MdDelete
  onClick={async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault() 
    await fetch(`/api/todo/${id}`, { method: "DELETE" });
    // You can then redirect, or refresh a state, etc...
  }}
  className="bg-red-400 hover:bg-red-600 p-1 text-3xl rounded-xl"
/>
```